# Are all defined points relative maxima?

Tags: calculus

> $f(c)$ is a relative maximum in the interval
>   $(a,b)$ iff $f(c) \ge f(x)$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$

Doesn't this imply *all* points are relative maximums by taking $a = c$ and $b=c$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is being defined is "relative maximum in the interval $(a,b)$. The definition should be saying something like: for a point $c\in (a,b)$, $f(x)$ is a relative maximum if for all $x\in (a,b)$ holds that $f(x)\le f(c)$.

Now, if $a=b$ then the interval $(a,b)$ is empty, so there are no relative maxima with respect to it.

Comment: Just to clarify: the end points are not included in the interval?

Comment: The open parentheses $(a,b)$ usually signify that the endpoints are not included. When the endpoints are included, the closed brackets $[a,b]$ are used. In this case, $(a,b) = \{x \mid a<x<b\}$, so $a=b$ implies $(a,b)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @WilliamStagner Makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If $a = b = c$, then $$(a, b) = (c, c) = \{x\in \mathbb R \mid c \lt x \lt c\} = \varnothing\;$$

Hence there exists no element, let alone one that is a relative maximum, in the "empty" interval.